# Android - Messages are ready to read, but I cant fetch them

Tags: java, android, client, message

Simple steps:

- Client writes a message and sends it to server (Works fine)
- Message gets delivered to server (Works fine)
- Server grabs the message (Works fine)
- Server handles the message and makes appropriate reply (Works fine)
- Server sends a message back to client (Works fine)
- Message gets delivered to client (Works fine)
- Client grabs the message (nop....problem)

As you see in the code; the size of the "oos" is actually increasing with every press, but I cant somehow read the data from oos.

When I press a button, Start gets called, and when I press another button Get gets called.

//Client

```
package com.example.clienttest;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Thread m_objThreadClient;
    Socket clientSocket;
    TextView serverMessage;
    EditText clientMessage;
    String sIn = "Nothing", sOut;
    DataOutputStream oos;
    DataInputStream ois;
    int i = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        serverMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        clientMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);


        m_objThreadClient = new Thread( new Runnable(){
            public void run()
            {
                try {
                    clientSocket = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 4000);
                    oos = new DataOutputStream (clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                    ois = new DataInputStream (clientSocket.getInputStream());


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    serverMessage.setText(e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        });
        m_objThreadClient.start();


    }

    public void Start(View view)throws IOException{
        sOut = clientMessage.getText().toString();
          try {
              oos.writeUTF(sOut);
              serverMessage.setText("Messages availible:" + ois.available() );

          }
          catch (Exception e) {
          }

    }
    public void Get(View view){
          try {

                sIn = ois.readUTF();
                serverMessage.setText("Message: " + sIn );
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
          }

    }

    public void onStop(){
        try {
            oos.close();
            ois.close();
            clientSocket.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

//Server

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.util.Hashtable;

public class Server2 {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket server = null;  
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(4000); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not start up on: " + "4000" + "Maby server is already open? Or a portforwording messup?");
            System.err.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Socket client = null;
        while(true) {
            try {
                client = server.accept();
                String IP = client.getInetAddress().toString();
                System.out.print(IP + " Connected\n");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Accept failed.");
                System.err.println(e);
            }

            Thread t = new Thread(new ClientConn(client));
            t.start();
        }
    }
}


class ClientConn implements Runnable {
    private Socket client;
    String Recv, Send;
    DataInputStream inFromClient;
    DataOutputStream outToClient;

    ClientConn(Socket client) {
        this.client = client;
        try {

            inFromClient = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            outToClient = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while ((Recv = inFromClient.readUTF()) != null) {

                System.out.print("Msg: " + Recv + " \n");
                if( Recv.equals("Hi")){
                    Send = "Welcome";
                }
                else{
                    Send = "Wat?";
                }

                outToClient.writeUTF(Send);
                System.out.print("Replying:" + Send + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print("No input ");
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

This really is confusing me :(....

Answer (score 0):

try to flush the data after you send some data from the server and have a try

```
 outToClient.writeUTF(Send);
 outToClient.flush();//add this one
```

and by the way when you click to call the `get()` method, the clients is expecting some message, where server is waiting for some message too, maybe you need to send something to get something, like this.

```
public void Get(View view){
          try {
                oos.writeUTF("What's up?!");
                oos.flush();
                sIn = ois.readUTF();
                serverMessage.setText("Message: " + sIn );
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
          }

    }
```

by the way, please follow Java naming rule, your methods follows m$ si-sharp naming rules `Get() - > get()` thanks. :)

Comment: Actually did, no use..
And btw, as said, the client GETS the messages cuz "Messages available show more than 1 with every click. So the problem is somewhere around "ReadUTF"

Comment: would you please comment where you think program stuck?! or some stack trace.., something..., and by the way maybe this is because server needs to accepts a message for response some message where you in get method just expect some message where you don't send something. I updated the answer.

Comment: The program seems to be wrong at "ReadUTF" on the client side, as I said the size of "ois" increases with every message sent to the server meaning there is actually some messages delivered back to the client. But the sIn string variable somehow doesnt assign that message to itself...

Comment: I see you buddy, well check the process flow in the server, as you see server first reads a String then process and sends the response, in client you must send something to get something, so how do you call the `Start()` method?! so maybe you need to call the `Start()` in `Get()` method before you trying to read some data, also flush the data in `start()` method. if client is stuck in `Get()` method, it means both client and server are waiting for each other.

Comment: As I said in the main post, Start and Get both get called by 2 seperate buttons, I press Start until I see that messages available are 6 in size or more. Then I go to Get but I cant read any single byte out of them. Server process flow works fine btw, I see the received message there and the message that the server will reply.

Comment: you know the `readUTF()` method BLOCKS the thread until some data is ready for return, so in your case, there is no data is ready for reading, so client blocks the thread until some data, and this is because the server does the same, so your process flow is send-read, while you just skip the send and trying to read.

Comment: btw, try to flush() data after each data writing

Comment: Dude the data GETS SENT SUCCESSFULLY to the server, and the server shows it, the server then replies with something and the client is unable to grab it,...but lets give your thought a try

Comment: BTW buddy, about the `readUTF() != null` I thinks it never returns null, and throws `EOFException` if reaches the end of the stream(that will not) or `IOException` if socket get closed.

Comment: I changed that too, now its just ReadUTF without any IF check. And the flush method as well didnt work :/ ...
My senior project is going to china x.x

Comment: So let me ask a stupid question, what if print(System.out) the `sIn = ois.readUTF();` just after this method!? I don't know, but maybe it's belong to client UI repaint! but it looks a little wired, but I believe we have stuck on something very simple.I really hope can give some hand, but seems I've failed till now.

Comment: Nah thanks for all help mate, really appreciate your effort :P
And yes this is just getting on nerves